# How to find the Name of the Subfolder in a Directory

Tags: c#, file, path, directory, substring

I have asked this type of a question before but this one IS different. I need to find the root folder of a folder.

For example:

I get is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice
C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice
C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice
C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice
C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice\Plugins
C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice\Plugins
C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice\Plugins
```

I used this code before:

```
DsVersions.ASSEMBLY2Row row = dsVersions.ASSEMBLY2.NewASSEMBLY2Row();
row.FOLDER = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
```

And then i found this code and thought it was the answer:

```
DsVersions.ASSEMBLY2Row row = dsVersions.ASSEMBLY2.NewASSEMBLY2Row();
DirectoryInfo directoryName = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
row.FOLDER = directoryName.Name;
```

After this code i was getting this:

```
NetOffice
NetOffice
NetOffice
NetOffice
Plugins
Plugins
Plugins
```

It's close but again all i need is Plugins. I have tried doing Path and File but it won't work, I always get an error.

Comment: What do you mean "all I need is Plugins"? Are you trying to treat the deepest, common directory as the root directory for a relative path?

Comment: What are the 7 fileNames producing this output ?

Comment: Do you mean the root folder as in C:\ or the parent folder, or what? You need to elaborate a bit more, we need more detail :)

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Kind of, Plugins is inside NetOffice, that is why i Don't need it, Plugins is a Subdirectory. Sorry if I'm being very confusing, I can't really explain things so well.

Comment: So what should you get for the first four paths? Nothing? "\"?

Comment: @BaliC Plugins is inside NetOffice and that's what i need, I selected a folder (NetOffice) and there is another folder in it Plugins, My program shows all of the files from both NetOffice and Plugins but i need to know what files are in Plugins.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Ya, I use a DataGrid to post all of these, there are other columns like Name, File, Folder, and Version. I am having a problem with Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            string rootDir = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
            string fileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
            if (rootDir.Length < fileDir.Length)
                row.FOLDER = fileDir.Substring(rootDir.Length + 1);
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the question and various comments, I infer that:

- You have a file path in hand
- That file is at the level *above* `Plugins`, i.e.:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice`

- You need to get the directories *under* that directory, but not that directory itself

If these assumptions hold true, then this will do what you ask:

```
var directoryName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice";

var directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);

row.FOLDER = directory
    .GetDirectories()
    .Select(subDirectory => subDirectory.Name)
    .Single();
```

Comment: Yes, you got the assumption correctly, but I can't use that, Yes i have tried it but nothing will show up if it won't be in row.Folder, I am using a DataSet with a data Grid. Is there any way to do it with a Substring?

Comment: @SovietOnion: `NetOffice` could possibly have many subdirectories, which doesn't fit into `row.Folder` because there is only room for one string. Are you saying that you expect *exactly* one directory always?

Comment: Yes, Plugins, It is the only one there.

Comment: @SovietOnion: I edited my answer to account for there being exactly one directory under `NetOffice`.

Answer (score 1):

For example:
you have the Sub Folder Plugins in Folder NetOffice, with the path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice\Plugins.

And you are trying to only get the name of the folder plugins, you can try the following code:

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice";
DirectoryInfo Dictiontory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo []Dir = Dictiontory.GetDirectories();// this get all subfolder //name in folder NetOffice.
string dirName = Dir[0]; //var dirName get name from array Dir;
```